# Obfuscating Softether through obfs4

Tags: vpn, softether, obfuscate

There's this problem I've been struggling with without any luck. Seemingly, Softether vpn connections are throttled down in my country, resulting in a max connection speed of 600-700 KBytes/s. On the other hand, I know for a fact that obfuscation of connections using Obfs4 (Tor's pluggable transport) works well, allowing them to remain undetected. I used obfs4 to obfuscate HTTPS proxy connections and a full speed of 2-3 MBytes/s was achieved.

The problem is that when I obfuscate Softether vpn connections by wrapping them inside obfs4 connections, the speed is still low (close to the same speed obtained from direct Softether connections, or probably lower). I need to know what causes this different behavior, while the obfuscation layer is working well in one case, but not in the other.

Maybe I should mention that obfuscation of Softether (SE) using obfs4 is not a straightforward task and requires modifying the routing tables in my case. This is because when direct SE connections are made by the client to a non-local host, the routing tables are automatically modified by the client, such that the default gateways are removed, and a routing item is added to the table to allow SE connections communicate with the server's IP address. However, this is not the case for local connections, and the routing table remains unmodified. Since I'm wrapping the SE connections using an Obfs4 client running locally, SE believes it's making local connections and does not change the routing table. So I manually remove the default gateways and add a routing address to the table. I'm almost certain that this process is performed successfully, but I still need to doubt it as a factor effecting my situation overall.

I know I may have not been very thorough in explaining the problem, so please let me know if you need any further information.

Thank you.

Comment: If the connection goes through, but slow, then it sounds like the routing tables were done right - else there'd be no connection. If SE is slow in either case, maybe it is the SE server that is slow or overloaded. Have you tried other VPN providers?

Comment: @SirAdelaide Thank you.
The slow connection is not probably related to overloading since: 1) the obfuscated HTTPS proxy on the same server delivers a high speed, and 2) I used to use direct non-obfuscated SE connections on the same server a while back and the speed was normal. This throttling down is probably recently applied and may be subject to change depending on the political issues of the day (in politically intense situations, the DPI system simply blocks all direct SE connections preventing them from initiation in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the reason is "UDP Acceleration", in which SE uses UDP connections in addition to the TCP connections it normally uses. For some reason, this option is disabled when an obfuscation layer is used (probably because Obfs4 is not configured to listen to the UDP ports required by SE for "UDP acceleration"). When direct SE connections are made with "UDP acceleration" disabled, a low speed is achieved similar to the obfuscated connections.

I'll be testing a little more to see what I can do about this.